# Using data attributes to filter a select box (using third party JS filtering code)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this relatively simple JS program:

http://www.barelyfitz.com/webdesign/articles/filterlist/

The program just filters a select box using a text box.

However, I want to jquery and HTML5 data attribute which is different how it was originally used.  I give my text box filterer a data attribute:

```
<input id="filter_text" name="filter_text" data-filterable="myselect" 
       type="text" />
```

I use the following `jquery` to get the name of the select box that is to be filtered and then filter the select box:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[data-filterable]').keyup(function() {
       select_box_name = $($(this).data('filterable'))[0];
       filter = new filterlist(select_box_name);
       filter.set(this.value);
    });
});
```

which NEARLY works.  You can filter but if you press backspace to de-filter then nothing happens i.e. it doesn't 'unfilter'.

It must be something really small!!

Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every `keyup` you're reinitializing `filter`. So you can only filter on the `select` as it is right when you press a key. Move the initialization of the filter out of the `keyup` event and it's working.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7FRFq/)'s a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the filter outside the event handler:

```
$(function() {
    $("input['data-filterable']").each(function() {
        var filter = new filterlist($($(this).data('filterable'))[0]);
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            filter.set(this.value);
        );
    });
});
```